# JQuery parentsUntil with element as variable not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, hierarchy, traversal

My problem is best explained with examples:

This works:

```
$(startContainer).parents().each(function(index, parentNode) {
    if (parentNode.isSameNode(commonContainer)) return false;
    console.log("start vert struc: " + parentNode.nodeName);
});
```

While, this does not work:

```
$(startContainer).parentsUntil(commonContainer).each(function(index, parentNode) {
    console.log("start vert struc: " + parentNode.nodeName);
});
```

Basically, the second version should work too as far as I know, but it doesn't. It simply does not stop when commonContainer hits, yet the first version does. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `parentsUntil()` is supposed to be a **selector**, not a node.

Comment: +1, [jQuery API reference for: `parentsUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/).

Comment: Ah, I was confused by your answer to my first question. I figured this meant that one can use nodes as selectors.

Comment: Oh sorry. It's sometimes important to double-check with me because I can get surprisingly muddled :-)

Comment: Note: this changed on jQuery 1.6 and now allows a DomElement